# Why is net logo showing a runtime error using with command

Tags: runtime-error, netlogo

first time poster.
I am a student working in netlogo.

I am running the Game if Thrones model and have an error.
The code works, but is appears when the humans defeat the nightlong, before the text comes up, I get an error message.

Code is:

```
If season = “winter” and count whitewalkers = 0 [
set season “spring”
ask patches with [ snow? ][
set snow? false
if else resources = 0 [
set pcolor brown
][
set pcolor green
]
]
user-message “The Night King has been defeated! Summer is back.”
stop
]
```

The error message is:

`WITH expected a true/false value from (patch 70 253), but got 0 instead. Error while observer running WITH Called bu procedure GO Called by button “go”`

Many thanks

I have tried removing the brackets, but I believe they are needed.
I have put more space in between the brackets, but that makes no difference.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518897/netlogo-with-expected-a-true-false-value-but-got-0-instead

Comment: Also: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/bind/article/common-netlogo-error-messages.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Netlogo WITH expected a true/false value but got 0 instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518897/netlogo-with-expected-a-true-false-value-but-got-0-instead)

Answer (score 0):

NetLogo does not perform type inference and the `?` at the end of such primitives is a convention to indicate to the reader of the code that it is a boolean type, but not a language feature. NetLogo’s compiler does not immediately assign a boolean value to a variable that has a `?` in its name, but simply assumes that it is an integer and assigns `0`.

You probably need to set the `snow?` variable to a default value before using it elsewhere in your code, probably on top of your model’s `setup` procedure.

Here is a simple piece of code to illustrate how to initialize boolean variables in NetLogo:

```py
patches-own [snow?]

to show-snow
  show "before assigning bool value"
    show [snow?] of patches
    
    ask patches [ set snow? false ]
    
    show "after assigning bool value"
    show [snow?] of patches
end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMjyS.jpg)